# SWT & JFace from command line

Tags: java, swt, jface

I 'm running bash shell in OS X and would like to try some SWT/JFace tutorials. I've downloaded eclipse (let's assume at $ECLIPSE_HOME) and swt.jar (let's assume at $SWT_HOME). Now, i would like to compile and run a SWT and/or JFace application from command line without running eclipse. I haven't set up CLASSPATH and i have both JDK 1.5 (OS X default) and JDK 1.6 installed. Could someone guide me with the steps needed to compile and run a simple SWT/JFace application ? Can i do that or everything must be done through Eclipse ? What's the difference using the Eclipse's swt (from $ECLIPSE_HOME/plugins/...) and the SWT jar i 've donwloaded from  the eclipse site ?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3):

[Here is a tutorial](http://wiki.eclipse.org/index.php/JFace) how to use JFace outside the eclipse platform. Have fun!